# Converting equations into Python and Excel VBA

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, excel-formula

I have a Geotechnical equation written in mathematical notation that I want to use in my Python code, I'm also testing it in Excel. In both instances I don't get the expected result - it should be a +ve number from 1-100 (%). I am assuming I've got the parenthesis in the wrong places. In the final version qc and Sigma_vo will be pulled from dataframe columns and I will run it will two Ko values.
[image]

```
import numpy as np
Ko=0.5
Sigma_vo=0.216
qc=0.0009

Sigma_m=Sigma_vo*(1+(2*ko))/3
Dr=((1/2.93)*np.log(qc/(205*(Sigma_m**0.51))))*100

print(Sigma_m)
print(Dr)
```

Comment: Do you have a reference/link for where the equations come from?

Comment: Usually equations like these are only valid over a limited range of values. E.g. for `Ko=0.5` and `Sigma_vo=0.216`, `qc` would need to be in the range `[76.3, 1428.9]`.

Comment: @xidgel. Ko will have two fixed values, creating two curves when I apply it to a dataframe column. 0.5 & 2.0. Sigma_vo will vary with depth below seabed (0.2 - 200), as will qc (0.9-840).  I just needed to be sure the equation is converted correctly into python. I can check I have everything in the correct units once I know the equation is correct.